# Outlook VBA .SendUsingAccount when no account is available

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

Story:
In Outlook App there is one default/user account and also additional inbox, calendar (let's call it 2nd_Account) etc. added (visible) as folders based on the Exchange Server permission.

I need to programmatically create new appointment item and send it on behalf of 2nd_Account. Problem is that in Application.Session there is only 1 account (the default one).

If done manually by user, then item created from 2nd_Account olCalendar folder is SendOnBehalf of the 2nd_Account, even though it is not included in Accounts collection. Any ideas, please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the appointment in the Calendar folder of that account - use `Store.GetDefaultFolder` instead of `Namespace.GetDefaultFolder`.

Comment: Actually solved with looping through folders collections
    `NameSpace.Folders`
and assigning desired folder to variable and using 
    `Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(strPath, olFolder)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I browse through the installed accounts in Outlook:

```
Set MAPISession = objOutlook.Application.Session     'Get the MAPI Outlook session
Dim WantedAccount as String ' Set to preferred account name

Set MAPIMailItem = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)  'Create a new mail message
With MAPIMailItem
  For Each Account In MAPISession.Accounts
    If Account = WantedAccount Then
      .SendUsingAccount = Account
      Exit For
    End If
  Next
```

Comment: Thanks but the point is that only one account is available (installed) while the Folders (inbox, sent, calendar) are available to the user based on Exchange Server permissions and therefore visible in Outlook. Actually solved with looping through folders collections
    `NameSpace.Folders`
and assigning desired folder to variable and using 
    `Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(strPath, olFolder)`